# FQDN hostname for both www and mail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hostname

My Linux server (Ubuntu) acts both as the http server and mail server.
Now I want to configure the mail server.
In */etc/hostname* I have to set the hostname.
My question is, can I have multiple hostnames for the server?

In the DNS I have setup

```
       A    12.12.12.12
www    A    12.12.12.12
mail   A    12.12.12.12
       MX   mail 10
```

Can I have this in */etc/hostname*?

```
www.mydomain.com  
mail.mydomain.com?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to list the multiple host names in /etc/hostname.  You only need to configure DNS to point the individual hostnames to your IP address.  You will need to check the documentation for your mail and http servers to configure the individual hostnames there as well.

For http (assuming you are using apache httpd as your web server), you could configure your hostname like this: (adapted from the configuration [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html))

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.otherdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Or better yet, leave off the NameVirtualHost line and replace the * with your IP address.

Comment: Great! I understand it better now. So it doesn't matter what hostname I actually choose for my machine (as long as it is setup in the DNS). And for both http en mail server I just setup the virtual hostnames (which are also setup in the DNS, www and mail respectively) in their own configuration files.

Comment: The hostname for the mail server will not be set up in the httpd configuration files.  It will be set up in the SMTP server's configuration.  On a side note, if you have a web front end for the mail server, that may be set up in the web server's configuration.

Comment: Exactly what I said: in their **own** configuration files, for apache in `httpd.conf` en for postfix in `main.cf`